# creating output from proc freq in SAS

Tags: sas

I am running the following SAS code in SAS Enterprise Guide 6.1 to get some summary stats on null/not null for all the variables in a table. This is producing the desired info via the 'results' tab, which creates a separate table for each result showing null/not null frequencies and percentages.

What I'd like to do is put the results into an output dataset with all the variables and stats in a single table.

```
proc format;
    value $missfmt ' '='Missing' other='Not Missing';
    value missfmt   . ='Missing' other='Not Missing';
run;
proc freq data=mydatatable;
    format _CHAR_ $missfmt.;
    tables _CHAR_ / out=work.out1 missing missprint nocum;
    format _NUMERIC_ missfmt.;
    tables _NUMERIC_ / out=work.out2 missing missprint nocum;
run;
```

`out1` and `out2` are being generated into tables like this:

```
FieldName | Count | Percent
Not Missing | Not Missing | Not Missing
```

But are only populated with one variable each, and the frequency counts are not being shown.

The table I'm trying to create as output would be:

```
field | Missing | Not Missing | % Missing
FieldName1 | 100 | 100 | 50
FieldName2 | 3 | 97 | 3
```

Comment: This may be helpful, if you add the formats to the `proc freq` + `table _all_;`, it will generate the desired table. https://gist.github.com/statgeek/e0903d269d4a71316a4e

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `tables` statement output options only apply to the *last* table requested.  `_CHAR_` resolves to (all character variables), but they're single tables, so you only get the last one requested.

You can get this one of two ways.  Either use `PROC TABULATE`, which more readily deals with lists of variables; or use `ODS OUTPUT` to grab the proc freq output.  Both output styles will take some work likely to get into exactly the structure you want.

```
ods output onewayfreqs=myfreqs;  *use `ODS TRACE` to find this name if you do not know it;
proc freq data=sashelp.class;
  tables _character_;
  tables _numeric_;
run;
ods output close;
```

Comment: thanks, I am new to SAS so it is helpful to know what different options are available. I came up with a messy solution using a combination of `ods output` and `proc sql`!